# How to share image to another app using intent in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to share the image from ImageView. I am able to set the image in imageView but when I am trying to share the image I am getting an error. I tried finding an article online but all of them are in java. So please can anyone help me with kotlin code.

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.StrictMode
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val builder: StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder = StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())

        var btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
        var iV = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iV)

        btn.setOnClickListener{
             var inTent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
             startActivityForResult(inTent,1)
        }


        }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        var iv = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iV)
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data != null){

            var image = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            iv.setImageBitmap(image)

            var share = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Share)
            share.setOnClickListener{
                var myinTent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                myinTent.type = "image/*"
                val uri = data?.data
                myinTent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri)
                startActivity(myinTent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to share image one running app to another app.??

Comment: @UmeshYadav Yes, like whatsapp or any other app.

Comment: `I am able to set the image in imageView` A bitmap you mean. Please tell better what you have. You have a bitmap. A thumbnail.

Comment: Do you wanna share a thumbnaul only or the original image?

Comment: `data?.data` will be null. Please confirm. With the intent you use you should share a file to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

need to share your image files without saving them to external storage? Can do and it reduces our code lines too.

From http://androidtechpoint.blogspot.com/2017/09/android-sharing-image-using-share-intent-without-saving-to-external-memory.html

> ```
> private void shareImage(Bitmap bitmap){
>   // save bitmap to cache directory
>   try {
>       File cachePath = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "images");
>       cachePath.mkdirs(); // don't forget to make the directory
>       FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath + "/image.png"); // overwrites this image every time
>       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
>       stream.close();
>
>   } catch (IOException e) {
>       e.printStackTrace();
>   }
>   File imagePath = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "images");
>   File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.png");
>   Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", newFile);
>
>   if (contentUri != null) {
>       Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
>       shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>       shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
>       shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));
>       shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
>       shareIntent.setType("image/png");
>       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choose an app"));
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> in your AndroidManifest.xml
>
> ```
> <provider
>     android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
>     android:authorities="com.vd.viewtobitmap.fileprovider"
>     android:grantUriPermissions="true"
>     android:exported="false">
>     <meta-data
>         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
>         android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
> </provider>
> ```
>
> filpaths.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
> </paths>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`val uri = data?.data` this is returning `null` .  Before send image save it as `File` in External cache directory . Then create `Uri` from that file .

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    var iv = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iV)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && data != null) {

        var image = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        iv.setImageBitmap(image)

        var share = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Share)
        share.setOnClickListener {

            try {
                val imageName = "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".png"
                val file = File(this.getExternalCacheDir(), imageName)
                val fileOut = FileOutputStream(file)
                image!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOut)
                fileOut.flush()
                fileOut.close()
                file.setReadable(true, false)

                var myinTent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                myinTent.type = "image/*"
              //  val uri = data?.data
                myinTent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file))
                startActivity(myinTent)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```